# Lauching program via command in php

Tags: php, cmd

i have tried to launch Firefox using the php exec() and system() function but it only launches up as a process in the task-manager without showing the browser window.What could be the problem?I have event tried using a bat and executing it to launch Firefox but its not working.I have tried many solutions from questions in this forum but non is working.Below is my code

```
    <?php
       exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START firefox.exe');

       system("cmd /c C:\my\project\folder\launcher.bat");

     ?>
```

Comment: Try to close your program in `Applications/Programs/Services` and have a try

Comment: still not working. a test with notepad shows it in the task-manager without its window.Is there any extra command i should add for the program to be show its window?

Comment: I found a useful comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059588/how-can-i-start-a-windows-gui-program-using-phpPHP applications started through IIS or Apache can not launch desktop applications without some significant permission changing.