# PHP 5.6.30 shell_exec start a process

Tags: php, shell-exec

I run a apache webserver on my windows 7 machine. And I got PHP 5.6.30 installed since I think it works best with mysql.

Im using `shell_exec("")`; to start a process by just visiting the php file. But I used to have the latest version of PHP but it didn't work with mysql that well so thats why I downgraded. But now `shell_exe`c won't start a process. I can still do taskkill with `shell_exec` and other stuff but its just the start command that seems to be broken

Example: `shell_exec("start notepad")`;

Comment: Please update your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, if your code does not work, it must be a bug in PHP :)

Comment: Also related and with good info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059588/how-can-i-start-a-windows-gui-program-using-php