# How to open a program on windows from php and have its GUI pop up for a certain user

Tags: php, windows, explorer

I had a simple script `exec('c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe')` or something similar that successfully started a new process (notepad.exe) on the php hosting computer. I even changed apache's user to the current human user account "TOM" on the machine just for this purpose, but still it only shows up in windows task manager as a process, and doesn't actually open the program in a usable way when accessing this script from another computer on the network.  Do I need to convince windows explorer to do something with the program to make it appear as an actual open program for windows user "TOM"?  Obviously I'm no windows expert but I really would appreciate some direction.

Comment: Ok i should have googled better... My answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8170050/1204690

Comment: The only straightforward solution (unless you're still running Windows XP) is for the user to run Apache from his session, rather than running it as a system service.  System services can't directly interact with the user.